# Create a multi-index dataframe from a 2D data frame - Turning a multivariate time-series array to lagged multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to turn a 2D multivariate time-series array of shape `(n_samples, n_channels)` into a DataFrame with a multi-index column given a maximum time-lag. The multi-index column would have the 'channel' at the first level and then the time-lag on the second level. Each row of the resulting dataframe would consist of one time window of the dataset.

### Example

I have a dataframe like the following, which is structured as (# of samples, number of variables) along the rows and columns. `x1` and `x2` are collected over time, so each row is a new time point.

```
  x1    x2 
0  0.23  0.32
1  0.80  0.68
2  0.39  0.33 
3  0.2   0.4
4  -1.   -1
5  5   8
```

I have a given "max lag" say value 2, which I would like to create a multi-index column of `x1: [lag0, lag1, lag2], x2: [lag0, lag1, lag2], ...`. The entries in the resulting dataframe would come from every nth component, where n is the max lag. So `x1-lag0` row 1 would have the value 0.23, but `x1-lag0` row 2 would have value 0.2.

I would like to convert my original dataframe into this new dataframe of (variable, lags) as a multi-index column and # of windowed-samples as the rows.

For the above example, the result would be:

```
 x1                x2                          
   lag0  lag1  lag2  lag0  lag1  lag2 
0  0.39  0.80  0.23  0.33  0.68  0.32 
1  5      -1    0.2   8     -1.   0.4
```

Note: the # of samples in the rows would now be the original # of samples / the maximum lag.

Comment: Can you add expcted ouput from sample data?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please try to clarify more.

Comment: @jezrael, I added an expected output. Lmk if there's still some questions tho

Comment: I check output and why is not swapped `-1` and `0.2` and `-1` and `0.4` in second row?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry that was a mistake. I fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new columns for final index and second level of `MultiIndex` by integer division by `//` and counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and last rename second level of `MultiIndex` by `lag`:

```
max_lag = 2

arr = np.arange(len(df))
df['g'] = arr // (max_lag + 1)
df['lag'] = df.groupby('g').cumcount(ascending=False)
print (df)
     x1    x2  g  lag
0  0.23  0.32  0    2
1  0.80  0.68  0    1
2  0.39  0.33  0    0
3  0.20  0.40  1    2
4 -1.00 -1.00  1    1
5  5.00  8.00  1    0


df1 = df.pivot(index='g',columns='lag').rename(lambda x: f'lag{x}', level=1, axis=1)
print (df1)
       x1               x2            
lag  lag0 lag1  lag2  lag0  lag1  lag2
g                                     
0    0.39  0.8  0.23  0.33  0.68  0.32
1    5.00 -1.0  0.20  8.00 -1.00  0.40
```

Test solution with if # of rows that are not nicely divisible by `max_lag`:

```
print (df)
     x1    x2
0  0.23  0.32
1  0.80  0.68
2  0.39  0.33
3  0.20  0.40
4 -1.00 -1.00
5  5.00  8.00
6  1.00  2.00
7  5.00  7.00
```

---

```
max_lag = 2

arr = np.arange(len(df))
df['g'] = arr // (max_lag + 1)
df['lag'] = df.groupby('g').cumcount(ascending=False)
print (df)
     x1    x2  g  lag
0  0.23  0.32  0    2
1  0.80  0.68  0    1
2  0.39  0.33  0    0
3  0.20  0.40  1    2
4 -1.00 -1.00  1    1
5  5.00  8.00  1    0
6  1.00  2.00  2    1
7  5.00  7.00  2    0

df1 = df.pivot(index='g',columns='lag').rename(lambda x: f'lag{x}', level=1, axis=1)
print (df1)
       x1               x2            
lag  lag0 lag1  lag2  lag0  lag1  lag2
g                                     
0    0.39  0.8  0.23  0.33  0.68  0.32
1    5.00 -1.0  0.20  8.00 -1.00  0.40
2    5.00  1.0   NaN  7.00  2.00   NaN
```

Comment: So `g` is the index in the "windowed sample" space. However, I think in this case, 'g' is incorrectly defined. It should be `arr // (max_lag + 1)`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: @ajl123 now is in sample data 6 rows,  so all working nice. Is possible 4 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 11 rows?

Comment: Oh yes, it is possible for it to have # of rows that are not nicely divisible by "max_lag".

Comment: @ajl123 - Anwer was edited. Also added new sample data.